# Android device uses resources from different density sets in debug and signed APK

Tags: android, dpi, screen-density, pixel-density

I noticed that my app shows slightly different layout on the same device depending on whether I am running the debug APK or the signed release APK. After much head scratching, I have isolated the problem to device density specific resource values. The device uses dimensions from v*alues-xxhdpi/dimens.xml* when I run the app in debug mode, and it uses dimensions from *values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml* when I run the signed APK. The device in question is Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 7.0

Just to confirm this, I created a new empty project with just a hello world string in it. I defined different values for the string in *values/strings.xml*, *values-xxhdpi/strings.xml* and *values-xxxhdpi/strings.xml*. Here are the results.

- Debug apk shows xxhdpi string. Works as expected.
- Running the release apk from android studio (by specifying a signing config in the gradle file) shows xxhdpi string. Works as expected.
- Generate a signed apk by selecting Build | Generate Signed APK and run it. This time the app shows xxxhdpi string. Why ?!

Why is this happening? Why is android selecting xxhdpi resources in debug mode and xxxhdpi resources in a signed APK?

Comment: It looks like I should be defining my custom dimensions in height specific dimension files like values-h800/dimens.xml etc. But my question is still valid.

Comment: can you post outputs of Analyze apks, It is present in Build | Analyze apk , then select the apks, Repeat same steps on the apks on which you are getting different output.
I checked on a sample app, worked fine on my phone, got same results everytime, with each method.

Comment: do you have different flavors ??

Comment: @AssemMahrous nope.

Comment: @Amarghosh Does it happen on other android devices (none samsung mobiles) too?

Comment: I have the same issue with a Samsung Galaxy S8